# GitHub: My push is just ignored

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a strange situation.  I've used git and GitHub a lot, and never had this.

I'm modifying a Github Pages site (where you have a `pagename.github.io` address).

I change index.html locally.  I commit, I push to master.  It pushes.

But the changes do not appear when I look on Github.

I try creating a new branch, `git checkout -b newbranch`, `git push --set-upstream origin newbranch`.  The branch does not appear on GitHub.

I have verified that the `git remote -v` does indeed return the expected repo on GitHub.

I'm at a loss.  Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Bad configured git? Can you push to any other repo?

Comment: What is the output of `git push`?

Comment: The usual: ` 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
petair:committeeoffun.github.io peter$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 318 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/<username>/<myrepo>.github.io.git
   4556ea8..7899c29  master -> master`

Comment: are you using git add --all before the commit? if you use gitk or git status you are seeing the changes correctly?

Comment: I've added all files (the files I'm editing were already added), I'm doing `git commit -am message`.  And to the first question, no, it seems I can no longer push to any repo (I can push, but the changes do not appear on Github.  No error occurs).

Comment: Ah, it looks like Github has been having server issues today... https://status.github.com/graphs/past_day .  Maybe that's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub repo doesn't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396828/github-repo-doesnt-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

Github was having server problems.  Things were getting pushed successfully, but there was a delay of an hour or so before they showed up.

You can check [here](https://status.github.com/graphs/past_day) if Github has server problems (though they somewhat understated the severity -- they just said they were recovering from minor issues).