# GitHub repo doesn't update

Tags: git, github

I made some changes involving a reset to the penultimate commit, followed by a change, a re-commit, and a tag change. Whereas I had just released `v1.0` on GitHub, I needed to fix something. So after cloning, I ran

```
git reset HEAD^
git tag -d v1.0
# changed my file
git commit -am "Move to version 1.0" # the same commit message as the one I undid above
git tag v1.0
git push --force --follow-tags
```

However, these changes don't appear on GitHub's interface. I can see that the changes were pushed, and they are even present if I clone a fresh copy of the repo. However, GitHub's graphical interface doesn't show the change.

The repo in question is https://github.com/The-Penultimate-Defenestrator/mathquill-evaluate

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Github's [Status](http://status.github.com) site:

> Some users may experience a delay in pushes or other changes appearing on the site.

That is as of 10:53 Mountain Daylight Time

Comment: This is probably the answer. I'll accept it if the repo updates by itself within a little while.

Answer (score 1):

If your last commit appears when you pull the branch again then I think you should not worry, seem that github facing issues on server and cannot update the commit status.
I have the same problem an hour ago but after a while, my new commit showed as normal.