# pushed commits not showing on Github

Tags: git, github

I have a [repository](https://github.com/TransformingMusicology/tabcode-haskell) on Github to which I have been pushing commits for several months. Today I prepared several commits and pushed them to the repo but they do not appear on the Github Web interface. I also pushed them to my institution's Gitlab instance and they have appeared on its Web interface.

Here's some information on the state of my repository:

```
$ git remote -v
github  git@github.com:TransformingMusicology/tabcode-haskell.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:TransformingMusicology/tabcode-haskell.git (push)
gitlab  git@private.com:transforming-musicology/tabcode-haskell.git (fetch)
gitlab  git@private.com:transforming-musicology/tabcode-haskell.git (push)

$ git push github master 
Counting objects: 34, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 4.82 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:TransformingMusicology/tabcode-haskell.git
   6f00bd1..1237971  master -> master

$ git push github master
Everything up-to-date

$ git branch -v
* master           1237971 Added rest tests
  xmlgen-serialise 54a4033 Removed unnecessary MEI duration to RhythmSign conversion function

$ git ls-remote github
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    HEAD
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    refs/heads/master
f52c681257855b9709ccae1a14f452683cfb00f3    refs/heads/xmlgen-serialise

$ git ls-remote gitlab
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    HEAD
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    refs/heads/master
f52c681257855b9709ccae1a14f452683cfb00f3    refs/heads/xmlgen-serialise

$ git ls-remote .
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    HEAD
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    refs/heads/master
54a403330731ca43c1cec953a7829d7f44e83c8e    refs/heads/xmlgen-serialise
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    refs/remotes/github/master
f52c681257855b9709ccae1a14f452683cfb00f3    refs/remotes/github/xmlgen-serialise
12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a    refs/remotes/gitlab/master
f52c681257855b9709ccae1a14f452683cfb00f3    refs/remotes/gitlab/xmlgen-serialise
ac5249bc29a4aff405f915ee0ff0e10dbddcde1d    refs/remotes/igor/master

$ git log
commit 12379718429dc54fa5f947b310b927b59e665c4a
Author: Richard Lewis <richard.lewis@gold.ac.uk>
Date:   Mon May 23 17:17:22 2016 +0100

    Added rest tests

commit f248550fa280174ec3fc0fa4c4e94b19e638c0d4
Author: Richard Lewis <richard.lewis@gold.ac.uk>
Date:   Mon May 23 17:16:57 2016 +0100

    Corrected rest parser
```

So it looks like `git` at least believes that the `HEAD` of the remote `master` branch is pointing to `123797`. But Github's Web interface is not showing this. Between that commit and my local repo's `HEAD` there are seven more commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
1237971 Added rest tests
f248550 Corrected rest parser
7612616 Added meter sign tests
9137281 Corrected meter sign parser
c06eec6 Setting up test suite
9de4ee3 Code tidying
61f0d48 Tidying up Cabal file
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: https://status.github.com/ they are experiencing technical issues

Comment: 11:53 CDT Some users may experience a delay in pushes or other changes appearing on the site. status.github.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub repo doesn't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396828/github-repo-doesnt-update)